# While running UploadJars utility in OIM following exception is coming

Tags: utility, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

While running UploadJars utility after giving all the parameters, utility is failing with following exception:

```
Logging configuration class "oracle.core.ojdl.logging.LoggingConfiguration" failed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.core.ojdl.logging.LoggingConfiguration
Error occurred in performing the operation:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.iam.platformservice.utils.JarUploadUtility.main(JarUploadUtility.java:232)
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What are the parameters you are passing to the script? Can you share all the responses you give to the utility?

Comment: I am not passing any parameters, I have just set required paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem.
We added

ORACLE_COMMON/modules/oracle.odl_11.1.1/ojdl.jar

(where ORACLE_COMMON is your oracle_common directory) to the start of our CLASSPATH and the error went away.
I think UploadJars.sh worked anyway, it was just writing out a problem with logging what it was doing.

btw, Note you might need to use UpdateJars.sh if an earlier version of the file already exists. You can check if the upload/update was successful by looking at the date in OIMHOME_JARS.UPDATED_ON.